# Unable to load leaftlet map

Tags: leaflet

I am following leaftlet js getting started tutorial. But I am unable to load the map. Here is the code I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.css" />
         <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    </head>

    <style>
        #mapid { height: 180px; }
    </style>

    <script>
    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'your.mapbox.project.id',
    accessToken: 'I have put public access token'
        }).addTo(mymap);
    </script>

    <body>

         <div style="margin-top:100px;margin-left:100px;height: 200px;width:200px" id="mapid"></div>
            <div style="height:200px;width:200px;background: red">
            </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above code, `id: 'your.mapbox.project.id'` I am unable to find this. I found only public access token, is this the reason map is not getting loaded .. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To learn leaflet, you can just use the options of the [example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example-basic.html) (check the source)

```
<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(mymap);

</script>
```

Later on, when you are more familiar with leaflet, you can open a [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) account and learn about what they are adding.

The reason why mapbox is mentioned in the home page of leaflet is because the creator of leaflet is now working for mapbox.

Comment: Alternatively, use a different tile service, for example `var positron = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {       attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'    }).addTo(map);`